# Adding values in a combobox from CSV file

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, combobox, pyqt

I have 2 combobox that get their values from a csv file.
The first combobox gets the name of car brands automatically when the GUI is launched.
The second combobox gets the different model of cars for the selected brand.

The problem that I have is that this doesn't work for all the brands.
For some of them, Python tells me that they're a *NoneType* and for others (the ones that work) that they are *str* . 
I don't understand how this is possible since I wrote the csv file the same way for all the entries.

Has this happen to anybody else before ?
Is this a csv issue or a python issue ?

(I'm using PyQt5 & Python 3.4)

Here is my code :

```
def carSelect(self):
   list = []
   list2= []

   with open (r"D:/MyFile/cars.csv", newline='') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
   for row inr eader:
      list.append(row[0])

      for d in list:
        if not d in list2:
           list2.append(d)
           ui.carBrand.addItem(d)

   ui.carBrand.currentIndexChanged.connect(p.carModel)

def Model(self):
   ui.carModel.clear()

   index = ui.carBrand.currentIndex()
   name = ui.carBrand.currentData(index)
   with open (r"D:/MyFile/cars.csv", newline='') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
   for row in reader:
      if row[0] == name:
        ui.carModel.addItem(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer !

It's not ***currentData*** that I have to use but ***currentText***

Thanks for the help.